# To create an app with Visual Studio (C#) that can password protect a PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm working on a project where we have SQL Server Reporting Services automatically saving a PDF report to a network folder.  We then want to password protect this file and email it to specified recipients.

Is it possible to create an app with Visual Studio (C#) that can password protect a PDF?

Comment: @msoliman Almost jinx :)

Comment: Using PDFSharp for commercial applications, if any security issues, i.e, weak password protection, etc.?